# How can I get my Linux laptop to detect its Intel GPU?

Tags: linux, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, optimus

I am running Kubuntu 14.04 on an HP Elitebook 8440p with NVIDIA NVS 3100m graphics. Currently, Linux only detects the NVIDIA GPU:

```
user@host:~$ sudo lspci | grep -E "VGA|3D"
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218M [NVS 3100m] (rev a2)
```

Since the processor is an Intel i5, I assume that the machine also has an integrated Intel GPU, but I'm stumped as to why it isn't showing up. I looked around in the BIOS, but I couldn't find any useful information or options pertaining to the graphics card — it's a business laptop, so the BIOS is not really geared toward that sort of thing.

The reason this is an issue is that I want to get Optimus working with the proprietary NVIDIA drivers. So far, when I've tried to enable the NVIDIA drivers, it makes the system unusable — just a black screen, presumably because the NVIDIA drivers assume that they can pass the job off to the Intel GPU, but the system doesn't know it has one. I'd really like to be able to use the Intel GPU, because using the NVIDIA GPU all the time cuts into battery life significantly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`lspci | grep -Ei "VGA|3D|graph"`, for example. Of course, it assumes that you're really have Intel graphics card.

And, talking about your "real" problem: you don't need to load drivers module manually. Just use Bumblebee + Primus (installation procedure depends on your distro)